# Unable to Fetch data due to not passing control check on Netlify Function API

Tags: cors, fetch, netlify

I am trying to send a fetch POST request to verify some data and return a key to a netlify function acting as a serverless backend. I can send this data from Postman with no problems, and the response body and headers come in fine, shown here:

[image: working body]
[image: working headers]

I want this API to be available from any domain, so I have included the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*' headers.

So, everything works in postman, but when I try to send an identical request from client-side javascript, I get this error:

[image: failed request and response]

This failure makes me think that I didn't include the correct CORS headers on the server-side, and theses are the CORS headers that I have right now:

[image: current server side cors headers]

Am I doing something wrong here? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you using any special headers in postman like `Accepts`?

Comment: @MaartenDev I have 2 custom headers in my postman request, but it works just fine in postman without them as well. They are just 'username' and 'password'. I think it may have to do with the pre-flight request failing somehow, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Do the response headers show up in the network tab from localhost? Are you handling the OPTIONS requests correctly?